# How do I handle Sign In Exceptions?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Hello I am new to flutter, I am making a social media app in which users are to signIn using email and password. I want to know how do I show users login errors such as Incorrect Password / Incorrect email etc. I am using firebase as back end database for application

I have successfully created both the login and registration parts of the application, but I am unable to show different errors. here is is my code someone please help me

```
Future LogIn(BuildContext context) async {
  FirebaseUser user = (await _Auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: getEmail(), password: getPass()))
      .user;
  try {
    if (user.isEmailVerified) {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomeScreen.id);
      //Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomeScreen.id);
      ClearAllInfo();
    } else {
      user.sendEmailVerification();
      Alert("EMAIL NOT VERIFIED").show(); //email not verified alert
    }
  } catch (e) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for `signInWithEmailAndPassword`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/signInWithEmailAndPassword.html) lists all possible errors:

- `ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL`
- `ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD`
- `ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND`
- `ERROR_USER_DISABLED`
- `ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS`
- `ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED`

Now, you can test for these in your `try`-`catch`:

```dart
try {
  FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(...); // Your signin call.
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  switch (e.code) {
    case 'ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD':
      // Handle wrong password.
      break;
    // Add other cases.
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Note that the `catch` block I added only catches `PlatformException`s. If you expect to see other exceptions, you might want to add another general `catch` block or `on` specific exceptions.

Comment: Thankyou so much for the quick response, I will try this. quick question where can I find the same documentation for Registration with email and Password. so I can do error alerts on that aswell

Comment: @junaidtariq You can find all functions [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth-class.html).

Comment: Thankyouu so much

Comment: I just tried what you mentioned but it doesn't appear to work, can you help me again @creativecreatorormaybenot

try{...}
on PlatformException catch (e){

    switch(e.code){
      case 'ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL':
        ErrorAlert(context, InvalidEmailtitle, InvalidEmailtext);
        break;
      case 'ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD':
        ErrorAlert(context, WrongPasswordtitle, WrongPasswordtext);
        break;
      case 'ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND':
        ErrorAlert(context, UserNotFoundtitle, UserNotFoundtext);
        break;
        ..........
    }

Comment: @junaidtariq Can you add a `print(e.code)` and `print(e.message)` before the `switch`? I might have messed something up there.

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD, The password is invalid or the user does not have a password., null)

Comment: I dont seem to be getting anything when printing, I added two strings before the statement to identify the e.code and e.message printed text but I dont see them in my console @creativecreatorormaybenot

Comment: @junaidtariq You have to move your `signInWithEmailAndPassword` into the `try` block mate. I updated my answer..

Comment: It's working now Thankyouu so much, You are amazing

Comment: I know it's a lot to ask but would you be so kind enough to help me with this question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58380075/flutter-shows-a-red-error-screen-before-loading-data-from-firebase-using-stream)